# Как сделать, чтобы после каждого сообщения от бота удалялось старое

Tags: python, telebot

Если не трудно, можете подсказать кодом как это сделать
Использую библиотеку telebot

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вставить этот код перед кодом отправки нового сообщения: `bot.delete_message(chatid,messageid-1)`